# Unity: Get an Instance to UI Object

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a working singleton class for game objects that I use for GameManager or Camera like common objects.It uses FindObjectOfType() function to create the instance if it is null. Everything works great on gameobjects. Now I'm trying to keep a panel under canvas above a game object. So I need an instance to the panel. My already written singleton class returns null when attached to a panel. How can I get an instance to a panel?

Comment: Access the image component of your singleton with `MyClass.instance.GetComponent<Image>()`

Answer (score 0):

You can get the instance of panel by declaring in the singleton class with GameObject type.

There is another way too.
You said you can get the instance of game object from singleton class.
And panel is above that game object.

So, you can get that panel like this.

```
GameObject panel = SingletonClass.Instance.GetGameObject().transform.parent.gameobject;
```

This will return the panel gameobject. You can get components of panel in normal ways.

e.g.,

```
panel.GetComponent<Image>();
```

Answer (score 0):

Just a suggestion, it is not a good practice to use `FindObjectOfType()` in runtime especially if you have a lot of objects in the game as it may become a cause of performance issues. If you are only doing it on once on setup, then you can disregard this suggestion.

One thing you can do is make a UIContainer singleton which is a MonoBehaviour. Then, let UIContainer have a serialized array of GameObject, and make a getter of UI instances from the UIContainer. You then assign the UI instances to the serialized array.

```
public class UIContainer : MonoBehaviour {
    private static UIContainer instance = null;
    public static UIContainer Instance {
        get {
            return instance;
        }
    }

    [SerializeField] GameObject[] uiInstances;

    void Awake() {
        instance = this;
    }

    void OnDestroy() {
        instance = null;
    }

    public GameObject GetUI(string uiName)
    {
        GameObject ui = null;
        foreach(GameObject inst in uiInstances){
            if(inst.name == uiName){
                ui = inst;
                break;
            }
        }
        return ui;
    }
}
```

Then if you need a UI instance, you can just call `UIContainer.Instance.GetUI("ui name");`.

This is just a sample of it so feel free to make your own or adjust this. This can also work if your UI is made from prefabs. Just change the array from instances to prefabs, but you have to do the instantiation logic from there. Keep the a reference of the instances then use that when using GetUI.